# Moq setup gives error System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I am writing Unit tests for controller class using XUNIT. Here is my code.

```
private Mock<StudentService> _StudentService;
private StudentController StudentController;

[Fact]
public void GetStudentsBySubject_ShoutReturnNotNull()
{
    List<StudentViewModel> Students = new List<StudentViewModel>();
 _studentService = new Mock<StudentService>();
    string Subject = "Math";
    _StudentService.Setup(x => x.GetStudentsBySubject(Subject))
      .Returns((Students));

    var controller = new StudentController(_StudentService.Object);

    var result = controller.GetStudentsBySubject(Subject);

    Assert.IsType<List<StudentViewModel>>(result);            
}
```

It throws error at line.

```
_StudentService.Setup(x => x.GetCheapestStudentsBySubject(Subject))
      .Returns((Students));
```

> Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I tried many changes. But nothing worked. What could I be doing wrong here.

The following error appears after fixing the nullreference error:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.GetStudentsBySubject(StudentControllerTests.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.Subject) Non-overridable members (here: StudentService.GetStudentsBySubject) may not be used in setup / verification expressions

Comment: Did you initialize "_StudentService" before use? (e.g. "_StudentService = new Mock<StudentService>()")

Comment: Regarding second problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828489/even-simple-moq-code-is-throwing-notsupportedexception

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `private Mock<StudentService> _StudentService;` has not been initialized and is still null.

You need to assign it a value first:

```cs
_StudentService = new Mock<StudentService>();
```

Edit: Your follow-up error means that you need to mark the method `GetStudentsBySubject`as `virtual`. Otherwise, Moq can't control the behavior of the method.

Comment: I added but still gives error. Sorry that my code had some typing errors. I have corrected them. It gives the following errors.System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.GetStudentsBySubject(StudentControllerTests.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.Subject)
    Non-overridable members (here: StudentService.GetStudentsBySubject) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Comment: @Techie see my follow up. add the `virtual` keyword to the GetStudentsBySubject method.

Comment: Can I fix it without changing the source method.

Comment: If you don't want to change the source method, you have to create an interface on StudentService and then mock the interface. Otherwise, no - the method has to be virtual.